# Limit with absolute value

Tags: functions, limits, absolute-value

I found this limit within the *Calculus Single Variable* book from Thomas.
$$ \lim _{x \to -2^-} (x+3) \frac{|x+2|}{(x+2)}$$

This is how I'm trying:
First of all, we need to found where the absolute value will apply.
$$|x+2|$$
$$x+2=0$$
$$x=-2$$
$$ -3+2<0 $$
$$ -1+2>0 $$

So the function will change of sign in this interval: $$(-\infty, -2)$$
Then I´m trying to solve by substitution but im stuck with the |x+2|, I don't know what to do within the absolute value :(. Thanks.

Comment: **Hint:**

$$
|x| = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
x & & x \geq 0
\\
-x& & x < 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: **Hint 2:** Split the limit as a product of two limits. You will need JavaMan's hint to evaluate one of them. [The other one is easy.]

Comment: Yeah, but do i need to replace the `-2` within the absolute value, or replace the x with an arbitrary value given by the interval created before.

Comment: If you're only interested in the limit from the negative side, can't you just replace $|x+2|$ with $-(x+2)$?

Comment: Please do not write things like "$-3+2=\mathrm{Negative}$". The number $-1$ is _not equal to_ the word "Negative", and the correct notation "$-3+2<0$" is both shorter and easier.

Comment: To get an intuitive idea of what might be going on, first do this. You want to know about $\frac{∣x+2∣}{x+2}$ when $x$ is a tiny bit to the left of $−2$, like $−2.0004$. Calculate the ratio, if necessary with a calculator (in this case, without is easier).

Comment: @André Nicolas: What do yo mean with ratio?

Comment: Divide one by the other, at $x=-2.0004$.  There, top is equal to ?.  Bottom is equal to ?.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The definition of absolute value is:
$$|a| = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
a & \text{if }a\geq 0,\\
-a & \text{if }a\lt 0.
\end{array}\right.$$

That means that (using $x+2$ for $a$):
$$|x+2| = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x+2 &\text{if }x+2\geq 0,\\
-(x+2) & \text{if }x+2\lt 0.
\end{array}\right.$$

When is $x+2\geq 0$? When $x\geq -2$. When is $x+2\lt 0$? When $x\lt -2$. So we can rewrite the above as:
$$|x+2| = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
x+2 & \text{if }x\geq -2,\\
-(x+2) & \text{if }x\lt -2.
\end{array}\right.$$

When you take the limit as $x\to -2^{-}$, you are considering values of $x$ that are very close to *and less than* $-2$. So for those values of $x$, you will have $|x+2| = -(x+2)$.

Comment: Ok understood :), just one thing, what about the indetermination of the denominator? thanks man

Comment: If you are evaluating the limit, you never actually plug in $x=-2$: you only consider what happens as $x$ gets close to, but is not equal to, $-2$. If $x$ is not equal to $-2$, the denominator is not "indeterminate". Since $x$ is not *actually* equal to $-2$, then $$\frac{|x+2|}{x+2} = \frac{-(x+2)}{x+2} = -1\quad\text{if }x\lt -2.$$